# Why filtering in big excel spreadsheet generates huge delay, but using vba solves it faster?

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I know this may sound very newbie, but I'd like to know some details about the internal process of Excel filtering.
A few years ago I came across a huge Excel spreadsheet (maybe more than 40 thousand or up to 80 thousand rows) and several columns. When we wanted to filter some data using Excel data filters, the spreadsheet almost collapsed. It took up to 2 or 3 minutes until the desired information would show up, and you shouldn't "bother" it by clicking on the file or you would get the "Not responding" message.
I found a simple code in VBA to actual change the filter's parameters but without actually opening the filters manually (not clicking on them) and the filter would return the filtered data in a matter of 1 second or less.
My question here is, what kind of information does Excel load in memory, so that when you click on a filter -if data is too much- the delay is high?
Because the only thing I did using VBA was actually setting the filter's parameters (i.e. "from the filter called 'City' only return 'Washington', 'Mexico City' and 'Montevideo', etc.)

Comment: I suspect that if you open a filter and Excel has to populate a dropdown, it will result in a very significant overhead (calls to the UI to create a "very big dropdown with checkboxes"). If you just set the parameters, none of that needs to take place. But I'm just guessing.

Comment: Thank you Floris, that seems to make sense. I'll keep on investigating though, but that gave me a clue.

Comment: I've noticed when working with *huge* tables, usually setting a filter is pretty quick, but when you press the "Clear" filter button it can take quite a while.
Changing CalculationOptions to "Manual" helps a lot - because even if there is a slow-calculation you can make many changes and then only recalculate once.